# Spring and Thymeleaf: How to move javascript to a separate .js file

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

Example:

This works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button th:onclick="'javascript:sayHello(\'hello\')'">Say Hello</button>
</body>

<script>
    function sayHello(text) {
        alert(text);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

But, if I move js to the file hello.js in the same folder, script is not working.

I tried embed like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{hello.js}"></script>
```

And like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="hello.js"></script>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you check which error do you have using developer tools in your browser? Maybe the hello.js file is not being loaded, change it to <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/hello.js}"></script> if you have it in your root context

Comment: Patrick, slash doesn't help. Message says "ReferenceError: sayHello is not defined"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are using default configurations from Spring Boot you should have your thymeleaf file in `src/main/resources/templates/` so you should put the javascript file in:

```
/src/main/resources/static
```

**Explanation**: your build tool (Maven or Gradle) will copy all the content from `/src/main/resources/` in the application classpath and, as written in [Spring Boot's docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content), all the content from a directory called `/static` in the classpath will be served as static content.

---

This directory could works also, but it is discouraged:

```
/src/main/webapp/
```

> Do not use the src/main/webapp directory if your application will be
>   packaged as a jar. Although this directory is a common standard, it
>   will only work with war packaging and it will be silently ignored by
>   most build tools if you generate a jar.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot Andrea.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Spring Boot documentation, static resources are served from /static, /public or off the classpath.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

There is also a brief mention of how to reload your static content and template files.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-reload-static-content